# How to get the text of a <div> tag which has sub elements along with direct text?

Tags: selenium

Can someone please help me in writing the XPath to get the text of a  which contains some other elements as well along with the text. Below is the HTML code:

```
<div class="message success fadable">
  Successfully Deleted        
  <a class="messageCloseButton" href="#">Close</a>
</div>
```

Expected Value:

Successfully Deleted

Comment: can you please let us know if you are using java/python?

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to locate the element and fetch the div text and to verify the actual and expected Result.

**1. Use Contains Method**

```
     var element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(text(),'Successfully Deleted')]"));
     string expectedResult = "Successfully Deleted";
     string actualResult = element.Text;
     Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult,actualResult);
```

**2. Second**

```
     var element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class = 'message success fadable'])]"));
     string actualText = element.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can not handle this situation in xpath. So you have to relay on the javascript to get the text nodes and return the value.

Here is the python solution.

```
def get_text_exclude_children(element):
    return driver.execute_script(
        """
        var parent = arguments[0];
        var child = parent.firstChild;
        var textValue = "";
        while(child) {
            if (child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)
                    textValue += child.textContent;
                    child = child.nextSibling;
        }
        return textValue;""",
        element).strip()
```

This is how to call this method in your case

```
ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='message success fadable']")
print(get_text_exclude_children(ele))
```

[image]

**Same Method in Java:**

```
public String get_text_exclude_children(WebDriver driver, WebElement element) {
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
return (String) js.executeScript("var parent = arguments[0];"
                                + "var child = parent.firstChild;"
                                + " var textValue = ''; while(child) { "
                                        + "if (child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)"
                                            + " textValue += child.textContent;"
                                            + " child = child.nextSibling; "
                                            + "} return textValue;",element);}
```

Comment: @Karthik is this solution helpful? were you able to resolve this issue?